# Make a jquery mobile popup disappear after two seconds

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

his question is asked earlier here, but I didn't get those answers to work. I work with a button:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="test_popup">
      <p>this is a test</p>
    </div>
<a href="#test_popup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" id="button_stop3">test</a>
```

And I tried putting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('popupafteropen', '.ui-popup', function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
  $(this).popup('close');
 }, 2000);
});

</script>
```

in the head section, but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

(I have multiple popups/buttons on the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time `setTimeout` executes the function, `$(this)` doesn't return *popup*. Instead, you should retrieve *popup* before running `setTimeout`.

```
$(document).on('popupafteropen', '.ui-popup', function () {
    var popup = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        popup.popup('close');
    }, 2000);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7ekuqz6j/)**

Comment: Oh! It was that simple... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PHPirate yes, that's all :)